# How to obfuscate key for encryption function?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, obfuscation, decompiling

If an encryption function requires a key, how do you obfuscate the key in your source so that decompilation will not reveal the key and thereby enable decryption?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to large extent depends on the platform and development tool, but in general there's no reliable solution. Encryption function is the point at which the key must be present in it's "natural" form. So all the hacker needs to do is to put the breakpoint there and dump the key. There's no need to even decompile anything. Consequently any obfuscation is only good for newbies or when debugging is not possible for whatever reason. Using the text string that exists in the application as the key is one of variants.

But the best approach is not to have the key inside, of course. Depending on your usage scenario you sometimes can use some system information (eg. smartphone's IMEI) as the key. In other cases you can generate the key when the application is installed and store that key as an integral part of your application data (eg. use column names of your DB as the key, or something similar).

Still, as said, all of this is tracked relatively easy when one can run the debugger.

There's one thing to counteract debugging -- offload decryption to third-party. This can be done by employing external cryptodevice (USB cryptotoken or smartcard) or by calling a web service to decrypt certain parts of information. Of course, there methods are also suitable only for a limited set of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is built into the .NET configuration system. You can encrypt chunks of your app/web.config file, including where you store your private key.

http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619921/how-do-you-hide-an-encryption-key-in-a-net-application)